# Shiny rendering googleVis HTML raw code

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I used googleVis to generate a chart object (x) then outputted it as:

```
cat(x$html$chart, file="y.html")
```

How do I input this raw .html file into a Shiny server.R and then get it to render properly on the ui? I can't find anything. I've tried with

`y <- readLines("y.html")
output$Plot = renderHTML(HTML(y))`

and

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel(""),      
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
       ...
    ),
    mainPanel({
      htmlOutput("Plot")
    }
    )
  )
))
```

but this just generates a blank area. I omitted sidebarPanel because I know that works with my `rendergVis()` code that I was running.

Anyone know how to do what I'm trying to do?

Comment: you need to supply the original code to your shiny server.ui

Comment: I did. I added more but I don't see how seeing that code helps you at all. The sidebar generates fine. The inputs work fine because they worked with directly rendering googleVis charts with the data. I want to change it to a basic HTML render so I don't have to load in all the raw data into the Shiny app environment, because the outputs are already stored in the HTML files I generated.

Comment: The html file probably contains HTML headers which won't work inside another html page. You can either extract only the googleVis part of the HTML, or try use `tags$iframe`.